# How to prove $\sup\{F(x)|x\in X\}=\sup\{G(y)|y\in Y\}=\sup\{f(x, y)|(x, y)\in X\times Y\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $X, Y$ be nonempty sets, and let $f$ be a nonnegative real-valued function defined on $X\times Y$. For each $x∈X$ and $y∈Y$, define $$F(x)=\sup\{f(x,y)|y∈Y\}, G(y)=\sup\{f(x,y)|x∈X\}.$$ Prove that $$\sup\{F(x)|x∈X\}=\sup\{G(y)|y∈Y\}=\sup\{f(x, y)|(x, y)∈X\times Y\}. $$

There are some computational examples that this statement is true, but I don't know how to start to prove this one.

Comment: Simple. Use the definition of sup.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to show that $\sup\{f(x,y):\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times Y\}$ is equal to each of $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$ and $\sup\{G(y):y\in Y\}$. I’ll get you started on the first of these; the second is similar.

Let $u=\sup\{f(x,y):\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times Y\}$, and suppose that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}<u$. Then by the definition of the supremum there must some $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle\in X\times Y$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)>\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}$. But then

$$F(x_0)=\sup\{f(x_0,y):y\in Y\}\ge f(x_0,y_0)>\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}\ge F(x_0)\;,$$

which is absurd. This contradiction shows that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}\ge u$.

Now suppose that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}>u$, get a contradiction to show that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}\le u$, and conclude that $\sup\{F(x):x\in X\}=u$.

Comment: I feel the first one you showed is absurd because
$$supF(x)<f(x_0, y_0)<F(x_0)<u$$
Is it right?

Comment: @PhilliP: The displayed chain of inequalities shows that $F(x_0)>F(x_0)$; **that** is what is absurd.